# Setting the first letter of a selection to be bigger and colored different than the rest

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007, styles

Is there an option or style where I can make a selection and on its first letter, have that be set at a larger font size, and possibly another color?

Say I have a selection of text all set to 11 point in black, but I would like the first letter to be at 14 point in red.

To give an idea, I would like a result like this:

[image: example]

How would I do this?

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the (best) answer given to your question.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a [Drop Cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial#Types_of_initials).

An article on how to do it can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/education/dropcap.aspx):

> On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Drop Cap**, and then click **Dropped** or **In margin**. Hold the mouse pointer over your choice to see a preview in your document.

There are options you can apply to change the font etc.

Comment: Thank you for the actual name, I had it on the tip of my tongue, and couldn't find it for the last 20 minutes.

Comment: It's not a style and not work on a Textbox. I'd like a result like this http://bit.ly/ddSfNL the "Summary" with first letter in red but also in Textbox